# Simple SQL Add data from cells with same Email

Tags: sql

I have this table with data like this.

**Email, Counter**
email1, 2
email1, 6
email2, 1
email2, 4
email3, 7
email4, 2
email5, 1

I need to get output like this:

**Email, Counter**
email1, 8
email2, 5
email3, 7
email4, 2
email5, 1

Comment: Note that you almost always want to specify which database you're using (both in the text of the question and the tags).  For any non-trivial question, there are likely to be at least subtle differences between the syntax that different databases would use.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT email, sum(counter) as counter
  FROM your_table
 GROUP BY email
```